# Sharepoint link from list to document library

Tags: excel, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I'm trying to create a list in Sharepoint that contains links to documents in a document library on the same Sharepoint site. What I've tried to do is to export the document library to an Excel file. This produces an ".iqy" file, that opens in Excel. I've copied the worksheet from the .iqy file to a regular Excel file, then added columns for the order to display and for the category (introduction, advanced, etc).

The resulting Excel file does exactly what I want: I can filter by category and the links open the document in Sharepoint. But when I create a new list in Sharepoint based on this Excel file, it doesn't work! The document names are imported as plain text and the URL is stripped. There's no option to import the column as a URL, just as "single line text", "multiple lines of text", etc. Is there any way to make the links work in Sharepoint as they do in the Excel file?

Comment: The reason I want to create a list is to be able to use custom headings and filters for at least two document libraries. I can create filtering for a document library but the column headings and column order must be the same for everything in the library. Also, a list resembles Excel more closely, making usage more intuitive